# Single SMTP Report

Tags: powershell

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail -Include *.bad -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "To: *@*.com"
```

The output of my query I just want the email address all by itself. Currently my output looks like this

```
C:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail\003b91651170707201800000012.BAD:2:To: user@domain.com
C:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail\003b91651170707201800000012.BAD:46:To: user@domain.com
C:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail\003c11119100507201800000007.BAD:2:To: user@domain.com
C:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail\003c11119100507201800000007.BAD:47:To: user@domain.com
C:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail\003c11119100507201800000007.BAD:48:Reply-To: user@domain.com
C:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail\003c60245022007201800000009.BAD:2:To: user@domain.com
C:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail\003c60245022007201800000009.BAD:47:To: user@domain.com
C:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail\003c60245022007201800000009.BAD:48:Reply-To: user@domain.com
C:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail\003e61810232107201800000010.BAD:2:To: user@domain.com
C:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail\003e61810232107201800000010.BAD:46:To: user@domain.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, but you're also capturing `Reply-To` (dunno if this is intended).  You can use a capture group to determine just the email address:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail -Filter *.bad -Recurse |
    Select-String -Pattern 'To:\s(.+@.+\.com)' |
    ForEach-Object { $PSItem.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what this is saying 'To:\s(.+@.+\.com)'

Comment: @user770022 That is regex which is what `Select-String` uses by default unless you're using `-SimpleMatch`.  It means capture the characters `To:` in a row, `\s` for whitespace class, `()` is a capture group, `.+` is wildcard 1+ characters, `@` at-sign character, and `\.` to escape the wildcard character for a literal period.  You can further expand it with anchors if `To:` appears at the start of a line, such as `^To:` which will stop capturing the `Reply-To` email addresses.

Comment: To exclude `Reply-To:` you could use a [negative look behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `Select-String -Pattern '(?<!Reply-)To:\s(.+@.+\.com)'`

Comment: With a capture group how can I get all the email addresses thats in those files?

Comment: Currently @TheIncorrigible1 it only returns one email address from the first file.

Comment: @user770022 See my edit.  It likely wasn't parsing all the objects.

Comment: Works great thank, is there a way to filter out a domain.

Comment: I just tried $email = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail -Filter *.bad -Recurse |
    Select-String -Pattern 'To:\s(.+@.+\.com)' |
    ForEach-Object { $PSItem.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
$email -isnot "*@domain.com"

Comment: @user770022 You can further filter the list with `Where-Object`:  `| Where-Object { $PSItem -notlike '*@domain.com' }`

Comment: I did this $email | select-string -Pattern "user@domain.com" - NotMatch. But its ugly